# How to use SSH key to commit as collaborator on GitHub?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I'm a collaborator on a private Github repo (owned by someone else), and although I have added an SSH key to my own GitHub account which allows me to authenticate when accessing my own repositories, it always asks me for my password when I try to access the repository on which I am only a collaborator.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't authenticate me with my SSH key?

I have tried to add my key as a "deploy key" to the shared repo itself, but GitHub always rejects my submission, with the error message "Key is already in use.".

My remote looks like the following:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://example-user@github.com/example-owner/example-project.git (fetch)
origin  https://example-user@github.com/example-owner/example-project.git (push)
```

Comment: Are you trying to push code trough `ssh`? How does link to your temote look like?

Comment: Added remotes above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've added the github repo as HTTPS instead of via SSH, your URL should look something like this

git@github.com:example-owner/example-project.git

If you check the right of the repo on github, you should see options to get the [image: links] via HTTPS, SSH, or subversion.